# printing wrong array size every time

Tags: c, arrays

This is a basic question but I am facing problem with array size.

Here, I am printing size of array in both **main function** and **size function**. In *main function* it prints correct size of array as **40** but in *size function* to whom I have passed array as a argument printing size of array as **8**.

I have tried with **void size(arr[SIZE] 'or' arr[] 'or' arr[10])** but output remains unchanged.

**Can anyone explain why this behaviour?**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define SIZE 10

void size(int arr[SIZE])
{
        printf("func_size() : size of array is : [%d]\n",sizeof(arr));
}

int main()
{
  {
      int var = 10;
  }
  {
      printf("%d", var); 
  }
  return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

func_main() : size of array is : [40]

func_size() : size of array is : [4]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because `arrays` when passed in functions get decayed into pointers (to the first element) in functions.

`sizeof` in `size()` returns the size of the pointer `arr`. Read about [Arrays and Pointers](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/c-faq/c-2.html/).

Comment: thanks a lot for answer...! Actually it was giving size as 8 in 64bit m/c and 4 in 32 m/c so got confused. Now I got my concept cleared...! thank you very much.